# Is Fourier dimension finitely stable?

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

Let $A,B$ be compact subsets of $\mathbb R$. Let $a=\mathrm{dim}_F(A)$, $b=\mathrm{dim}_F(B)$ be their Fourier dimensions, respectively. My questions are as follows:

1. Is it true that $\mathrm{dim}_F(A\cup B)=\max\{a,b\}$?
2. If $A$ and $B$ are positively separated, is it true that $\mathrm{dim}_F(A\cup B)=\max\{a,b\}$?
3. In addition to 2, if $A\subseteq [0,1]$ and $B\subseteq [2,3]$, is it true that $\mathrm{dim}_F(A\cup B)=\max\{a,b\}$?
4. In addition to 3, if $a=0$, is it true that $\mathrm{dim}_F(A\cup B)=b$?

I have searched online but I cannot find any references for that.

Answer (score 2):

You might find section 5 of the following survey paper handy: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322983671_A_Survey_on_the_Fourier_Dimension.